# How can i give 100 ms for next function?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this function in my js file. I need to give time for doTimerA. I want to start doTimerA after 100ms. Right now in this function both is chosen same time.

```
function ReLoadBuy(){
    if (myclick == "2")
    {
        ReLoadBuygo();
    }
    else
    {
        StartBuy();
        doTimerA();
    }
}
```

Anything i must add?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout( doTimerA, 100);
```

Insead of this:

```
doTimerA();
```

Comment: If answer was helpful don't forget to accept it, and welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

`window.setTimeout (doTimerA, 100)` should do the trick. Although you might want to check the compatibility with all the browsers. I don't think there would be a problem but do double check just to be sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delay the execution of `doTimerA()` for 100ms use the following call:

```
window.setTimeout( doTimerA, 100 );
```